# sap compatible utc timezone values from ISO 8601 timestamp

Tags: java, webmethods

I have a requirement where I need to extract SAP compatible timezone values from ISO 8601 timestamp which also contains utc values with colon. I am working in webMethods but a java solution would help.
Sample of results that I am looking for are

**UTC+11** for input 2018-03-27T01:02:43.745+11:00,

**UTC+103** for input 2018-03-27T01:02:43.745+10:30,

**UTC+93** for input 2018-03-27T01:02:43.745+09:30

Comment: 1.get the last index of +,:.
2.get the substring from +to :.
3.delete leading 0.
4.after : get the first number.
5.ignore 4 if it is 0.else add to result.
6.add UTC+ to result.

Comment: Not knowing SAP, should +01:30 and +13:00 both produce **UTC+13**??

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTimeFormatter offsetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ZZZ");
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-27T01:02:43.745+11:00");
    String offsetString = offsetFormatter.format(dateTime);
    String sapOffsetString
            = offsetString.replaceFirst("^([+-])0?(\\d+?)0{0,2}$", "UTC$1$2");
    System.out.println(sapOffsetString);
```

This snippet outputs

> UTC+11

I have tested with the other two examples from your question too.

The `ZZZ` format pattern string formats the offset into a string like `+1100`. The `replaceFirst` operation removes one leading and up to two trailing zeroes, leaving at least one digit. And prepends `UTC`. So `+0000` becomes `UTC+0` and `-0030` becomes `UTC-03`.